# Using Parameter in SSRS to lookup field and filter results

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS to create an employee anniversary list for HR. All the data I need is in two tables which I have joined in a single dataset, but I keep getting errors like:

> Failed to evaluate the FilterValue of the Grouping 'Details'.
>   (rsFilterEvaluationError).

A simplified version of my data is attached as an image. I want to use the Employee ID as a parameter and from that Employee ID look up the Position Code for that Employee. That Position Code will then determine what Employees are shown in the Anniversary List. For example, when the President opens the report, because his id is 500, the report will see that his position code is President and then only display employees that have "President" in the Reports To field. I'm having trouble with translating the Employee ID into the Position Code and then using that Position Code to filter the report.

Any ideas from the pros out there would be most appreciated!

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 12.0.4468.0

[image: DataSimple]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to get a list from Table A where their 'manager' is the passed in employeeid from table b? Can you post some sample data from both tables and then the desired output. I'm sure this will be fairly simple once we have that.

Comment: This is easier done in your sql proc. Send the params to SQL and filter on the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, this was a simple one.  Embarrassing though it may be, the problem I was having was that the parameter data type was not set to integer, it was text.  So it didn't match the integer related lookup I was trying to use and was giving weird errors.  So bottom line: gotta watch those data types.  Thanks everyone for your suggestions and help.